# Create [react-jss] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

[react-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss) is the implementation of [jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss) for use in React.

There is currently a [jss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jss) tag and a [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag - which Stack Overflow thinks [react-jss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jss) is too similar to and told me to request here.

For posterity - here is the question I was asking where I thought a [react-jss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jss) tag was warranted.

[Is string comparison the right way to do dynamic styling for variants in React-JSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416801/is-string-comparison-the-right-way-to-do-dynamic-styling-for-variants-in-react-j)

Comment: Do others plugins have their own tag?